# Perl Module::Build test run cannot find dynamically loaded module

Tags: perl, unit-testing, module-build

I am building a Perl module using `Module::Build`. The `Build.PL` file is below:

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;

use Module::Build;
my $build = Module::Build->new
(
    module_name => 'Company::LDAP::SyncAttr',
    license     => 'perl',
    installdirs  => 'vendor',
    install_path => {
                      'bin'    => '/usr/bin',
                      'script' => '/usr/bin'
                    },
) ;

$build->create_build_script ;
```

The module itself is here:

```
# SyncAttr.pm
package Company::LDAP::SyncAttr;
use Authen::Krb5;
1;
```

I have a test file in `t/test.t` that looks like this:

```
# test.t
use Company::LDAP::SyncAttr;
```

When I run `./Build test` I get this error:

```
t/test.t .. Can't load '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/auto/Authen/Krb5/Krb5.so' for module Authen::Krb5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/auto/Authen/Krb5/Krb5.so: 
undefined symbol: krb5_free_krbhst at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.20/DynaLoader.pm line 187.
 at /tmp/gg/blib/lib/Company/LDAP/SyncAttr.pm line 3.
Compilation failed in require at /tmp/gg/blib/lib/Company/LDAP/SyncAttr.pm line 3.
```

If I run the test.t file *directly*, I get no such error:

```
perl -Ilib/ t/test.t
```

What do I have to do to get `./Build test` to not error out?

**UPDATE**: The problem lies with Module::Build. There is a routine `do_tests` in the `Module::Build::Base` module that *forces* the environment variable `PERL_DL_NONLAZY` to 1. If I change that line to set `PERL_DL_NONLAZY` to 0, then the tests all pass. The module `Module::Build::Base` does not provide an option to not set `PERL_DL_NONLAZY`, so I have submitted a bug report asking them add such an option. In the meantime, I will just have to skip running `./Build test`.

Comment: `perl -Mblib t/test.t` would be more representative.

Comment: Did you run `./Build` before `./Build test`?

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, Isn't the former included in the latter.

Comment: @ikegami I would expect that, but I don't see any mention of it in the documentation. Haven't looked at the source yet.

Comment: Tip: Authen::Krb5 should be listed as a prereq.

Comment: The direct problem is that Authen::Krb5 is trying to link to symbol `krb5_free_krbhst` in `libk5crypto` or `libcrypto`, but it can't find it for some reason. It's really wonky that it happens only some circumstances, and might requires extensive debugging. My best guess is a change in environment. Add `BEGIN { warn "$_: $ENV{$_}\n" for sort keys %ENV }` before any `use` statements in `test.t` and run it both ways.